# How to create verticle divider which grows dynamically with page length

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a layout like shown in the picture.[image]

I am using twitter bootstrap 3.

My current empty page layout looks like following

```
    <jsp:include page="includes/topmenu.jsp" />

<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<jsp:include page="includes/footer.jsp" />
```

Now i need to design the whole page inside row class.

How can i achieve this ? is there already a free template available like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find answer here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
Personally I would divide the contents something like that:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">photo</div>
<div class="col-md-6">tabs</div>
<div class="col-md-3">nothing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Heads up! These docs are for v2.3.2, which is no longer officially supported.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar thank you, I knew something seemed wrong :D Never used the old version, so I didn't know about the differences and assumed the documentation is right.

Answer (score -1):

[A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/7Kmd3/)

### HTML

```
<div class="box">Some terrible bootstrap tabs</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    min-height: 100%;

    /* just for display purposes */
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    width: 50%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: "How to create verticle divider which grows dynamically with page length" was your question. You don't need bootstrap or any other over complex crutch to create this.

Comment: Try buddy press. That looks what you are trying to make.